# Any alternative of Python Transfomer Package in java?

Tags: python, java, rest, machine-learning, nlp

I am loading a Python model from Hugging Face.

A pretrained model used to generate answers of questions from a given context.

Model Description:
[model link page](https://huggingface.co/deepset/roberta-base-squad2)

**Model loading sample:**

```
from transformers import AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, AutoTokenizer, pipeline

model_name = "deepset/roberta-base-squad2"

# a) Get predictions
nlp = pipeline('question-answering, model=model_name, tokenizer=model_name)
   QA_input = {
      'question': 'Why is model conversion important?',
      'context': 'The option to convert models between FARM and transformers'
}
 res = nlp(QA_input)
```

It is using a Python transformer package to load it. Now I can create its API in Python easily, but I want to create an API of this model in Java, where its parameters ('Question' & 'Context') will be given by the user itself.

Now I want to know, how will I load this model in Java? Is there any transformer dependency in Java?

Comment: If all the Python dependencies are compatible, you could run it on GraalVM with [GraalPy](https://github.com/oracle/graalpython).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert model to ONNX runtime format  and then run it through Apache OpenNLP, you can read [this tutorial](https://blogsarchive.apache.org/opennlp/entry/accelerate-hugging-face-transformer-models) and this [documentation](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/manual/opennlp.html#intro.models.onnx)

the class `SentenceFeatureGeneratorFactory` might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can run Python code from a Java application using the subprocess module
refer this [blog about python and java usage](https://towardsdev.com/executing-a-python-script-from-a-java-file-and-vise-versa-ea73dda0026e)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).